# How can I delete a stl file from my scene?

Tags: three.js, webgl, stl-format

I need to load some stl files when clicking on a button, the problem is that every time I click on this button a new stl is loaded OVER the previous one. How can I clean my scene before loading the next file? Thank you!

This is my function that loads the stl and is called when I press the button
(there are just two stl files in this example but I'm supposed to have a lot more):

```
function loading(){

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {ambient: 0x555555, color: 0xAAAAAA, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200} );

    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();

    loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

        var geometry = event.content;
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

        mesh.scale.set( 0.02, 0.02, 0.02 );
        mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
        mesh.castShadow = true;
        mesh.receiveShadow = true;
        mesh.needsUpdate = true;    
        geometry.dynamic = true;

        scene.add( mesh );  
    } );

    if ( assembly[0] == 2 && assembly[1] == 2 && assembly[2] == 2 && assembly[3] == 1 ){
        loader.load( '2_2_2_1_1_0.stl');}
        else { loader.load( '1_1_1_2_0_1.stl'); }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the previous mesh from the scene

```
scene.remove( mesh );
```